# Transfer Learning twice

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I had a data set that was really small and so found another data set that was very similar and trained it on that one first but used pre-trained model (DEnsenet 121). After training this initial model I now want to remove the output neuron and replace it for the final model head, after loading the model weights , how do I remove the last layer and replace it with another and still be able to pick which layer I can freeze, I have tried everything on google search I  have seen

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you less remove the last layer, but rebuild the model layer by layer, using the weights of your first pretrained model. Then instead of the original last layer, you use any layer as you wish

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got you right, but what you could do is load the model from Keras and set the `include_top` variable to `False`. With this, you "remove" the top and can add your own Dense Layers for classification. There is also the possibility to freeze or unfreeze the layers by simply setting the `layer.trainable` component to `false` (So freezing it).
here is a short example with `ResNet50`:

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(self.img_height, self.img_width, 3))
    # Freeze layers 0 to x
    for layer in base_model.layers[0:-1]:
        layer.trainable = False

    """for layer in base_model.layers[23:-1]:
        layer.trainable = True"""

    # add a global spatial average pooling layer
    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    # let's add a fully-connected layer
    x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
    #x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
    x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
    #x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
    # and a prediction Layer with number of classes and softmax function
    predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
```

In the for loop you can set which layers you want to freeze and which to train. After that you can add your Dense Layers after doing a Pooling operation or whatever you want to do.